# Using a date-time-picker in react and meteorjs

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am trying to place a date time picker in my form. However, I get an error that says Invariant Violation, Target is not in the DOM. I am very new to javascript as well as meteor and react. What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/drwofle21/8cffed99312711ddfb3f

Answer (score 1):

As the comment on the Gist said "document.getElementsByClassName("calendar") Will return an array, not single node."

That array contains a list of nodes that you can loop through. Best thing to do is console log it out and see what it's actually returning and how you can best handle it.